# Binomial Theorem Bijective Proof

Tags: elementary-set-theory, proof-explanation, combinations, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

### Background

The coefficient of $x^ry^{n-r}$ is the number of terms with exactly $r$ $x$'s before grouping.

For example, $(x+y)^3=xxx+xxy+xyx+xyy+yxx+yxy+yyx+yyy=x^3+3x^2y+3xy^2+y^3.$

"#" = number.

Some proof of the binomial theorem claims that

#of terms with exactly $r$ $x$'s before grouping = #of $r$-subsets of $\{1,...,n\}$ = $C(n,r)$ or $n\choose r$

There is an implicit bijection such that the each subset corresponds to the position of the $x$'s.

### My Question

What is an example of such a subset of an $r$-subset of $\{1,...,n\}$? Is this equivalent to saying $r$-element subset?

Thank you.

Comment: "...an $r$-subset of $\{1,...,n\}$? Is this equivalent to saying $r$-element subset?" : Yes, it is equivalent.  One example of an $(r)$ subset of $~\{1,2,\cdots,n\} ~: ~r \leq n~$ is $\{1,2,\cdots,r\}.$  Incidentally, the binomial theorem rests on the intermediate result that the number of ways of selecting $k$ distinct items from a set of $n$ distinct items, sampling without replacement, where $n \in \Bbb{Z^+}$ and $k \in \{0,1,\cdots,n\}$ is $$\binom{n}{k} = \frac{n!}{k![(n-k)!]}.$$  ...see next comment

Comment: One way of proving this *Pascal's triangle* oriented intermediate result is by using the fact that $$\binom{n}{k} + \binom{n}{k+1} = \binom{n+1}{k+1}.$$  Using Mathematical Induction, along with this result, the formula for the number of *Combinations* of $n$ things, taken $k$ at a time, follows.  That is, there are two ways of constructing a $(k+1)$ subset of $\{1,2,\cdots,n+1\}$.  You can either extend a $k$ subset of $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}$ or you can extend a $k+1$ subset of $\{1,2,\cdots,n\}.$